# Batch script to mass rename by modify date

Tags: batch, script, batch-rename

I'm trying to make a batch script to mass rename files by modify date and time of each file. I'm new at this and searching since this morning and nothing lead me in the good way. SHould I use xcopy, robocopy, powershell ? Is there a place for batch scripting with examples ?

I'm also wondering if It's possible to make a drag&drop script (I take files with my mouse and drop them on the script to be processed). It works when I drag&drop a single file on a .bat script but I don't know for multiple files.

Thank you for your help.

NB : I can't use mass renamer softwares because I'll use this script very often and I would like to automate the processing.

Comment: Why does needing to run often block the use of software? Do you mean that it will be run on lots of computers? I also assume this is Windows?

Comment: Yes have a look at xcopy  and the /D: switch, you will need to call other batch files into the one you drag and drop the files, but you will need to run it from command prompt and specific the files or folder

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried and where you got stuck. Including your current script and what effort you've put into researching this is a bonus.

Comment: What does your script look like so far?

Comment: It looks like a dirty script like this. And it stop after renaming the first file. No doubt there is a simplest way to do so.
@ECHO OFF
dir /B > fileList.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %i in (fileList.txt) DO ren "%i %j %l" %l

Answer (score 1):

There is free software such as [Ant Renamer 2](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer/features) that has command line parameter options. You create an ARB file (Ant Rename Batch file) that you call from the command line. You can have it be one renaming step, or a series of steps that you want to run in sequence.

You did not provide an example renaming scheme, but Ant Renamer allows you a lot of flexibility when it comes to renaming files based on their creation or modification date:

[image]